# How should I treat outdoor wooden stairs to preserve them?

Tags: wood, painting, stairs

I plan to replace outdoor wooden stair planks.  They are exposed to Florida heat and rain. I planned to paint them brown so they match their peers.

However, do they need any other treatment so that they will endure the test of time?

Comment: Your stairs are Peer reviewed?

Answer (score 3):

You would want to treat them with a waterproofing/sealer first and then wait the required dry time before painting them.

You might be better off staining them brown. Stairs take  beating and paint might just crack and peel off.  There are a lot of stain/sealers out there to choose from.

Comment: Good answer JACK. Here in the great wet NW we tend to stay away from any solid sealing finishes . They tend to crack, flake and peel, exposing the wood.  Instead I prefer oiling wood that will directly exposed to the weather.   Yeah, you have to touch it up every 2-3 years. Maybe after a pressure wash and light sanding. It's important to do your research on penetrating oils first, bc products like Behr were awful.   I like Pentofin personally (yeah, I know product recommendations aren't welcome here, sorry).

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson Down here in southern Florida we stay away from the solid sealing too. The heat just destroys them. Have you noticed a lot of crazy projects going on since covd-19 started?  Stay safe George.